# How to implement e-commerce tracking code in magento website

Tags: magento-1.7

The brief procedure, How to add e-commerce tracking code in Magento website.

Comment: http://cutroni.com/blog/2008/01/22/google-analytics-e-commerce-tracking-pt-2-installation-setup/

Answer (score 2):

**What We'll Cover**

Enabling E-Commerce Tracking
Tracking Codes
In order to properly track E-Commerce data using Google Analytics, you need to install your own SSL Certificate.

**Enabling E-Commerce Tracking**

**1.** Login to your Google Analytics account.

**2.** Open the site for which you want to enable e-commerce tracking, and click on it.

**3.** Click Admin on the navigation bar.

**4.** Select View Settings in the right column.

**5.** Set the default page to index.php.

**6.** Switch Ecommerce tracking to the On position.

**7.** Click Save.

**E-Commerce Tracking Code**

`Paste the following into your Bigcommerce Control Panel under Setup & Tools › Web Analytics.`

Be sure to replace **UA-XXXXXXX-X** and yourdomain.com with your own number and domain in the following codes.

Universal Analytics

If your Google Analytics profile is using Universal Analytics use this code.

How can I tell if I am using Universal Analytics?

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', 'yourdomain.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

function trackEcommerce() {
this._addTrans = addTrans;
this._addItem = addItems;
this._trackTrans = trackTrans;
}
function addTrans(orderID,store,total,tax,shipping,city,state,country) {
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': orderID,
    'affiliation': store,
    'revenue': total,
    'tax': tax,
    'shipping': shipping,
    'city': city,
    'state': state,
    'country': country
});
}
function addItems(orderID,sku,product,variation,price,qty) {
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': orderID,
    'sku': sku,
    'name': product,
    'category': variation,
    'price': price,
    'quantity': qty
});
}
function trackTrans() {
    ga('ecommerce:send');
}
var pageTracker = new trackEcommerce();
</script>
```

Standard(async) Analytics

If your Google Analytics profile is using Standard Analytics use this code.

How can I tell if I am using Standard Analytics?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

function old2new() {
    this._addTrans = addTrans;
    this._addItem = addItem;
    this._trackTrans = trackTrans;
}

function addTrans(orderID,store,total,tax,shipping,city,state,country) {
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
    _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
        orderID,
        store,
        total,
        tax,
        shipping,
        city,
        state,
        country
    ]);
}

function addItem(orderID,sku,product,variation,price,qty) {
    _gaq.push(['_addItem',
        orderID,
        sku,
        product,
        variation,
        price,
        qty
    ]);
}

function trackTrans() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);
}

var pageTracker = new old2new();
</script>
```

Comment: Please cleanup this answer

Comment: I am doing same

Answer (score 1):

Using Piwik:

I recommend installing Piwik and https://github.com/integer-net/Piwik

Then configure in backend of both and tada, ready